# C++ problems passing array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int recursivefunction(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int prevlevel, int currentlevel,     int thearray[] ) {
currentlevel = (prevlevel + 1);
if(prevlevel = 0) { currentlevel = 1; }  //only ensures that the FIRST run has no issues with negatives
while(thearray[currentlevel] < (NbProducts - NbPlates + 1)) {
    if(currentlevel = NbPlates) {
        cout << thearray[currentlevel] << endl;  //debug, do something to test full program
        }
        else recursivefunction(NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray[] );
    }
}
int main() {
int NbProducts = 10, NbPlates = 3, prevlevel = 0, currentlevel = 0;
int thearray[100];
recursivefunction (NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray[]);
}
```

and it keeps giving me "expected a value before the ']' in "thearray".
Ignore the rest of the program, it doesn't do anything right now. If I give a value inside of those brackets it gives me a multitude of other errors. Any ideas?

Comment: try passing *thearray and try

Comment: You need to remove `[]` from the variable when you call the function.

Comment: Use `recursivefunction (NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray)`. Remove the `[]` after `thearray`.

Comment: hey; that returns the following:

error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
  recursivefunction (NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray);


the arrow is pointing right at the end of "thearray" any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function, it should pass the array itself w/o []

```
recursivefunction (NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray);
```

Comment: hey; that returns the following: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive] recursivefunction (NbProducts, NbPlates, prevlevel, currentlevel, thearray); the arrow is pointing right at the end of "thearray" any ideas?

Comment: int recursivefunction(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int prevlevel, int currentlevel,     int * thearray )